# What are the 'things' Euron Greyjoy has seen that we couldn't imagine?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In "The Dragon and the Wolf" (*Game of Thrones*, S07E07):

> After Cersei is shown the wight, Euron Greyjoy asks if they can swim, and proceeds to tell Cersei/everyone, "I've been around the world, I've seen everything, things you couldn't imagine, and this, this is the only thing I've seen that terrifies me."

I know that this may have simply been an opportunity for

> Euron to (actually) travel to Essos to ferry the Golden Company back to Westeros.

However, I'm still curious, as it makes sense for Euron, being a seafarer, to have experienced many unusual things.

**So what unimaginable things has Euron witnessed?**

Comment: As you said, it surely fits the show they put on. 

As for possible "things" he might have seen, let's start with normal horrors. He is by far the most feared pirate on the known seas. His ship is named Silence since he cut off the tounges of all his man. Gods know what butchering and torture he done or witnessed.

As for more exotic things, I think he even liked these rumors to be spread about him. We know from the shore that he sailed as far as Qarth. Also, rumors say he more than once went to old Valyria, hoping to uncover some juicy secret. So could be few things he actually saw.

Comment: He also may have seen the stone men, faceless men, warlocks, miracles performed by red priests/priestesses, or things we haven't heard of. We don't really know, though, as this line from him is about the only clue we have.

Comment: The question is not entirely unanswerable, but relies on the *unfinished book counter part with some things being questionable as the book series is set up to be a pov and there are, in some cases, unreliable narrators. But to answer shortly, Euron's story dances around Dany's and his Essos adventures come with interesting mythological objects of interest.

Comment: He has seen HBO's other original programs like *The Sopranos*, *OZ* and **gasp** *True Blood*!